# How do I develop a DotNetNuke module from scratch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to develop a module for DotNetNuke 7 however 90% of the tutorials use templates which I really want to avoid. The other 10% are just simple hello world modules.

I was wondering if anyone could share a simple module project with database access and database queries that I could study or simply tell me what I need to do to go about doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Templateless Module Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312401/templateless-module-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the modules on the [DNN Forge](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forge) are open source, if you want to peruse their source code.  We also have some simple (and not simple) modules on [our GitHub account](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/) (the simplest being [Tell-A-Friend](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/Engage-Tell-a-Friend/), [Jackrabbit](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/Engage-Jackrabbit/), and [Take-Out](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/Engage-Take-Out/))

Comment: Thanks, truly the best way is to look at what others have done and it is helping, however, for the database I ended up using SqlDataSource and I think it's an easier route than everything else I've seen on the web.

Comment: So far as data access goes, there are two concerns when working with DNN.  First, the DNN schema isn't a public API, so it can and does have breaking changes occur during upgrades.  Second, if you're going to distribute your modules, you'll want to support the `objectQualifier` and `databaseOwner` tokens in your SQL (see http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/sql-scripts).  But if you're developing just for an environment you own, then you don't need to worry about that, and you can use whatever data access strategy you want.